# Parent nodes rendered as normal node when all children are not visible

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Is there any way to customize parent nodes or turn off their compound node mode when each node under it is set to display: none?

I am currently trying to edit the expand-collapse extension, in order to set collapsed nodes to display: none, instead of removing them from cytoscape.

Instead of removing them those elements are given the `.cy-expand-collapse-hidden` class and styled with

```
{
  selector: '.cy-expand-collapse-hidden',
  style: {
    'display': 'none',
  }
},
```

Normally with the extension, when the nodes are removed it no longer is a parent node and is thus customizable as I have done
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrask.png)

With my current changes it sets the collapsed nodes to `display: none` and they are hidden in cytoscape but still accessible (editable/deletable/selectable) but the parent node they are collapsed under is still a parent node and stuck un-customizable even though the nodes under it are not displayed. Shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDD7Q.png)

Basically I'll detect when each node under it is hidden but I just need a way to manually tell a parent node to render as normal node and not a box.

Or possibly add this as a feature, as the parents already detect when children are not visible in order to not include them in its bounding box.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing a lot of information. Pleas look at ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to improve your question. Add every information you have that might help us, but keep it as short as possible. You can also take this short [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about Stack Overflow. Also don't get discouraged if your question is voted down, this is your best indicator to improve your question.

Comment: Please add your code, not just the small part of your stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the cytoscape.js extensions, I'd suggest expand-collapse, which renderes parents as normal nodes as you desire:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    layout: {
        name: 'cose-bilkent'
    },
    style: [
        {
            selector: 'node',
            style: {
                'background-color': '#ad1a66'
            }
        },
        {
            selector: ':parent',
            style: {
                'background-opacity': 0.333
            }
        },
        {
            selector: "node.cy-expand-collapse-collapsed-node",
            style: {
                "background-color": "darkblue",
                "shape": "rectangle"
            }
        },
        {
            selector: 'edge',
            style: {
                'width': 3,
                'line-color': '#ad1a66',
                'curve-style': 'straight'
            }
        },
        {
            selector: 'edge.meta',
            style: {
                'width': 2,
                'line-color': 'red'
            }
        },
        {
            selector: ':selected',
            style: {
                "border-width": 3,
                "border-color": '#DAA520'
            }
        }
    ],

    elements: [
{"data":{"id":"nwtN_50c55b8c-3489-4c4e-8bea-6a1c1162ac9c"},"position":{"x":577.5410894097904,"y":612.5647477282114},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_3a5d1ad1-5bfe-48e7-99ee-0cdf3913b062","target":"nwtN_743ee692-2363-4e76-a0c2-d6d3f717953e","id":"nwtE_6d4afc19-88a0-4fd4-9fbf-3591cb6ba062"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_8753a0df-286b-4f9b-a00d-bc093113bac7","target":"nwtN_9a23093c-257f-4e74-9f74-34cdf693daec","id":"nwtE_605f28bd-77c0-4eef-8251-c5ba9668bda7"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_1b72ec9f-c49f-4768-85a7-16ac6ff345e3","target":"nwtN_7813a042-3f67-44ab-9d83-ced928bedd25","id":"nwtE_5bafa3fe-246a-477c-849c-3284c3e62578"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_d578fedc-d576-4c07-8406-89956b346a9d","target":"nwtN_6fb77c5b-4321-4c3c-a941-91a951082e71","id":"nwtE_6dda445b-530e-4b95-a3b1-e09cabc73993"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_ef9670aa-321a-41ba-a665-c3980f30eb2a","target":"nwtN_9a23093c-257f-4e74-9f74-34cdf693daec","id":"nwtE_b6195365-55fd-4e16-b03d-af46585b2618"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_7813a042-3f67-44ab-9d83-ced928bedd25","target":"nwtN_477a1284-d1e7-44c6-8553-92fa8a6a553d","id":"nwtE_6f57baf0-3722-4012-b33e-783c267645fa"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_9d2ac5f6-093a-4090-a750-942e7464a15f","target":"nwtN_6fb77c5b-4321-4c3c-a941-91a951082e71","id":"nwtE_9fac6ca3-d907-4b5a-8496-b0edbc3815ca"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_6fb77c5b-4321-4c3c-a941-91a951082e71","target":"nwtN_f95babe0-0c64-4076-b380-fad5605fec6e","id":"nwtE_ac487e12-218a-45fd-b94a-f8fb51494baa"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_04d7dde6-171a-4179-85f5-a0cf510f55fb"},"position":{"x":195.56340747734816,"y":484.3338177685355},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_9d2ac5f6-093a-4090-a750-942e7464a15f","target":"nwtN_e79b5f83-1e09-485f-83cb-f85c9c6dae25","id":"nwtE_24228974-e8ba-4f05-8fe8-e775d314bcff"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_01047009-f54b-4c2a-8153-3d83c6e32eab","target":"nwtN_6af44d07-59d1-4773-bab6-c99641e4810b","id":"nwtE_56a86996-2c25-4071-b3a3-3000057eef90"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_65df5546-116f-4bda-92c7-acc6549589f1","target":"nwtN_30d6a1fb-f835-4d67-98db-dbfd8e91166e","id":"nwtE_a690584d-974b-4a78-8169-584dc4aa2ef8"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_fc734e6e-c7c1-446f-8ae6-a3935cbb8b29","target":"nwtN_1f8d5d5d-f085-4317-84d4-7b8612d11367","id":"nwtE_bca25d80-d197-41ca-871c-9c3806a802c3"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_6fb77c5b-4321-4c3c-a941-91a951082e71","parent":"nwtN_717d31aa-6b70-4067-bcf2-13e0f6bd879a"},"position":{"x":424.9142621725959,"y":163.663834699366},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_d578fedc-d576-4c07-8406-89956b346a9d","parent":"nwtN_717d31aa-6b70-4067-bcf2-13e0f6bd879a"},"position":{"x":489.2620636399552,"y":205.99231330748833},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_6fb77c5b-4321-4c3c-a941-91a951082e71","target":"nwtN_1b72ec9f-c49f-4768-85a7-16ac6ff345e3","id":"nwtE_fdd46d3d-3529-4552-bcaf-e5a43364d5eb"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_9d2ac5f6-093a-4090-a750-942e7464a15f"},"position":{"x":307.4167261049662,"y":242.51235456419},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_f95babe0-0c64-4076-b380-fad5605fec6e","parent":"nwtN_717d31aa-6b70-4067-bcf2-13e0f6bd879a"},"position":{"x":433.25389502259094,"y":81.8501883151051},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_f95babe0-0c64-4076-b380-fad5605fec6e","target":"nwtN_1b72ec9f-c49f-4768-85a7-16ac6ff345e3","id":"nwtE_9298d0d5-8159-4b50-b880-48aa19738a86"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_6b82a0c0-db1a-4aed-8434-f56152c6bac1","target":"nwtN_65df5546-116f-4bda-92c7-acc6549589f1","id":"nwtE_449cf49b-88e5-44f9-9300-5a8dbd79c135"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_30d6a1fb-f835-4d67-98db-dbfd8e91166e"},"position":{"x":579.7696102042084,"y":292.2890755756693},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_65df5546-116f-4bda-92c7-acc6549589f1","target":"nwtN_8753a0df-286b-4f9b-a00d-bc093113bac7","id":"nwtE_15b708e3-501d-432c-941d-627df912946f"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_ef9670aa-321a-41ba-a665-c3980f30eb2a","parent":"nwtN_50c55b8c-3489-4c4e-8bea-6a1c1162ac9c"},"position":{"x":540.8474401288637,"y":548.2864791672267},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_8de3d737-f713-404d-a181-c065f9cce74f","target":"nwtN_50c55b8c-3489-4c4e-8bea-6a1c1162ac9c","id":"nwtE_fd0f48e7-988f-4707-b126-b8a04dc3f64c"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_3a5d1ad1-5bfe-48e7-99ee-0cdf3913b062","target":"nwtN_8de3d737-f713-404d-a181-c065f9cce74f","id":"nwtE_7049cf2c-cc2b-40ed-94b8-590e2b703c45"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_1f8d5d5d-f085-4317-84d4-7b8612d11367","target":"nwtN_ef9670aa-321a-41ba-a665-c3980f30eb2a","id":"nwtE_28f94f80-370a-4819-b01e-7c14286528d6"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_1c510598-47d3-48a4-ba9d-fdfb915cda10","target":"nwtN_04d7dde6-171a-4179-85f5-a0cf510f55fb","id":"nwtE_4b91ec16-80c7-476e-ac78-40ec11628f8c"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_1b72ec9f-c49f-4768-85a7-16ac6ff345e3","target":"nwtN_477a1284-d1e7-44c6-8553-92fa8a6a553d","id":"nwtE_580dc718-3a38-4131-8527-5966dc7117bd"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_717d31aa-6b70-4067-bcf2-13e0f6bd879a"},"position":{"x":491.63465589698114,"y":136.22441840106094},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_9a23093c-257f-4e74-9f74-34cdf693daec","parent":"nwtN_50c55b8c-3489-4c4e-8bea-6a1c1162ac9c"},"position":{"x":609.4769080081592,"y":540.0632700234723},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_91e530f8-4a18-423b-ae2b-0f87ae72d824","target":"nwtN_787d128e-8256-4207-9e34-948bd142f842","id":"nwtE_c1260ab9-e976-4b02-a0d4-28e4e7b71956"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_6af44d07-59d1-4773-bab6-c99641e4810b","target":"nwtN_65df5546-116f-4bda-92c7-acc6549589f1","id":"nwtE_1379f27c-2858-4c7c-b305-f9dbef07f992"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_f95babe0-0c64-4076-b380-fad5605fec6e","target":"nwtN_477a1284-d1e7-44c6-8553-92fa8a6a553d","id":"nwtE_70a9c66e-a05d-4795-9830-b941aa0bdf8d"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_1b72ec9f-c49f-4768-85a7-16ac6ff345e3","parent":"nwtN_717d31aa-6b70-4067-bcf2-13e0f6bd879a"},"position":{"x":491.4678555276823,"y":133.24054767963713},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_65df5546-116f-4bda-92c7-acc6549589f1","target":"nwtN_d578fedc-d576-4c07-8406-89956b346a9d","id":"nwtE_3a1a451a-396c-46dd-844a-09c8c4506788"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_1f8d5d5d-f085-4317-84d4-7b8612d11367","parent":"nwtN_50c55b8c-3489-4c4e-8bea-6a1c1162ac9c"},"position":{"x":597.8765594527064,"y":612.7761198138919},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_6b82a0c0-db1a-4aed-8434-f56152c6bac1","target":"nwtN_6fb77c5b-4321-4c3c-a941-91a951082e71","id":"nwtE_03b7f374-f923-4cbd-9b1c-358e6bd0a66a"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_d578fedc-d576-4c07-8406-89956b346a9d","target":"nwtN_1b72ec9f-c49f-4768-85a7-16ac6ff345e3","id":"nwtE_bdaaa9a5-5464-44eb-a69a-177006535c60"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_7813a042-3f67-44ab-9d83-ced928bedd25","parent":"nwtN_717d31aa-6b70-4067-bcf2-13e0f6bd879a"},"position":{"x":558.3550496213663,"y":140.29772029134818},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_477a1284-d1e7-44c6-8553-92fa8a6a553d","parent":"nwtN_717d31aa-6b70-4067-bcf2-13e0f6bd879a"},"position":{"x":508.5039225894028,"y":66.45652349463356},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_9a23093c-257f-4e74-9f74-34cdf693daec","target":"nwtN_1f8d5d5d-f085-4317-84d4-7b8612d11367","id":"nwtE_06738526-f767-4e34-8d41-bfd8b046d48e"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_fc734e6e-c7c1-446f-8ae6-a3935cbb8b29","parent":"nwtN_50c55b8c-3489-4c4e-8bea-6a1c1162ac9c"},"position":{"x":614.2347386907171,"y":685.0662254329505},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_1c510598-47d3-48a4-ba9d-fdfb915cda10","target":"nwtN_8de3d737-f713-404d-a181-c065f9cce74f","id":"nwtE_874c0108-f1b5-4331-9580-bbc904d5ed52"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_30d6a1fb-f835-4d67-98db-dbfd8e91166e","target":"nwtN_7813a042-3f67-44ab-9d83-ced928bedd25","id":"nwtE_8ecc2707-8d9f-4c5a-b79f-36028161a2de"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_3a5d1ad1-5bfe-48e7-99ee-0cdf3913b062"},"position":{"x":390.8088604802138,"y":631.143932383176},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_1c510598-47d3-48a4-ba9d-fdfb915cda10"},"position":{"x":385.86501672672586,"y":549.4623389479385},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_01047009-f54b-4c2a-8153-3d83c6e32eab"},"position":{"x":420.38955421084455,"y":471.15574980196067},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_e79b5f83-1e09-485f-83cb-f85c9c6dae25"},"position":{"x":369.7167651842458,"y":293.0403182947785},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_2ac61ffd-0f55-4d76-ac39-f12efc1712ba"},"position":{"x":418.05570853622856,"y":392.34060880148394},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_6af44d07-59d1-4773-bab6-c99641e4810b"},"position":{"x":488.8353737093525,"y":424.0878886254484},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_6b82a0c0-db1a-4aed-8434-f56152c6bac1"},"position":{"x":438.2063143421404,"y":315.0732399204851},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_8de3d737-f713-404d-a181-c065f9cce74f"},"position":{"x":449.9163565836266,"y":594.1831978504854},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_65df5546-116f-4bda-92c7-acc6549589f1"},"position":{"x":511.65889587382577,"y":346.18005665157585},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_8753a0df-286b-4f9b-a00d-bc093113bac7"},"position":{"x":562.2598442850485,"y":415.8153103233126},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_9d2ac5f6-093a-4090-a750-942e7464a15f","target":"nwtN_04d7dde6-171a-4179-85f5-a0cf510f55fb","id":"nwtE_11040a46-0530-4375-a13d-2cdca0a98536"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_ef9670aa-321a-41ba-a665-c3980f30eb2a","target":"nwtN_6af44d07-59d1-4773-bab6-c99641e4810b","id":"nwtE_b47d4380-4724-4409-a449-1d80a798f9df"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_e79b5f83-1e09-485f-83cb-f85c9c6dae25","target":"nwtN_6b82a0c0-db1a-4aed-8434-f56152c6bac1","id":"nwtE_b7156db8-08d3-4a8d-9b43-db3de0701017"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_6b82a0c0-db1a-4aed-8434-f56152c6bac1","target":"nwtN_2ac61ffd-0f55-4d76-ac39-f12efc1712ba","id":"nwtE_1ab89f57-598a-4805-85d6-445f44bed701"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_2ac61ffd-0f55-4d76-ac39-f12efc1712ba","target":"nwtN_01047009-f54b-4c2a-8153-3d83c6e32eab","id":"nwtE_3a06bd73-a5ea-42fc-bebd-6cc9b227c4d4"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_01047009-f54b-4c2a-8153-3d83c6e32eab","target":"nwtN_1c510598-47d3-48a4-ba9d-fdfb915cda10","id":"nwtE_fe9dae92-bb4d-4fbc-8b00-3275e457899b"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_1c510598-47d3-48a4-ba9d-fdfb915cda10","target":"nwtN_3a5d1ad1-5bfe-48e7-99ee-0cdf3913b062","id":"nwtE_498e1c01-8c7d-4711-86d4-25119fd459b3"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_91be4b3b-b492-4cf2-822e-c2a1de14dbfe","parent":"nwtN_d70e8589-ab02-41e3-879f-29aed04212fa"},"position":{"x":131.35922693271124,"y":605.7954433087209},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_743ee692-2363-4e76-a0c2-d6d3f717953e","parent":"nwtN_d70e8589-ab02-41e3-879f-29aed04212fa"},"position":{"x":263.1586191787393,"y":578.1716399433802},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_4d5b8b52-1f20-45f8-bc0f-3a4a1235c0f5","parent":"nwtN_d70e8589-ab02-41e3-879f-29aed04212fa"},"position":{"x":195.2099595474637,"y":563.255374790295},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_b282d9cf-0120-42bc-9036-3bd48f925d1e","parent":"nwtN_d70e8589-ab02-41e3-879f-29aed04212fa"},"position":{"x":256.9500139684577,"y":508.8943151396569},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_0bd04732-5c51-4577-87f3-3675b3294ac3","parent":"nwtN_d70e8589-ab02-41e3-879f-29aed04212fa"},"position":{"x":127.96819577595704,"y":535.5200800812347},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_d70e8589-ab02-41e3-879f-29aed04212fa","parent":"nwtN_04d7dde6-171a-4179-85f5-a0cf510f55fb"},"position":{"x":195.56340747734816,"y":557.3448792241888},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_0f5340ab-a217-423f-b5f7-0a149f3217e8","parent":"nwtN_04d7dde6-171a-4179-85f5-a0cf510f55fb"},"position":{"x":253.48384362872935,"y":375.70472845792517},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_91e530f8-4a18-423b-ae2b-0f87ae72d824","parent":"nwtN_04d7dde6-171a-4179-85f5-a0cf510f55fb"},"position":{"x":187.4692319760543,"y":341.24719222835006},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"id":"nwtN_787d128e-8256-4207-9e34-948bd142f842","parent":"nwtN_04d7dde6-171a-4179-85f5-a0cf510f55fb"},"position":{"x":119.07770758703417,"y":363.03066656565034},"group":"nodes","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_4d5b8b52-1f20-45f8-bc0f-3a4a1235c0f5","target":"nwtN_91be4b3b-b492-4cf2-822e-c2a1de14dbfe","id":"nwtE_720b0a71-9ad3-4821-b828-ecace971acd1"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_91be4b3b-b492-4cf2-822e-c2a1de14dbfe","target":"nwtN_0bd04732-5c51-4577-87f3-3675b3294ac3","id":"nwtE_ce9e18ee-2bb9-4abb-88f8-272b3d76a8b4"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_743ee692-2363-4e76-a0c2-d6d3f717953e","target":"nwtN_4d5b8b52-1f20-45f8-bc0f-3a4a1235c0f5","id":"nwtE_6a465aa8-1c8b-4455-95bc-e67b77f3f7d3"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_b282d9cf-0120-42bc-9036-3bd48f925d1e","target":"nwtN_743ee692-2363-4e76-a0c2-d6d3f717953e","id":"nwtE_c6b430bd-17fc-4b1f-82a9-16bc0d5dfa78"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_0bd04732-5c51-4577-87f3-3675b3294ac3","target":"nwtN_4d5b8b52-1f20-45f8-bc0f-3a4a1235c0f5","id":"nwtE_12dd751b-6a30-4bef-8511-d36869559740"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_4d5b8b52-1f20-45f8-bc0f-3a4a1235c0f5","target":"nwtN_b282d9cf-0120-42bc-9036-3bd48f925d1e","id":"nwtE_7944e4ea-bb97-484f-a6ee-0d77d7bab80f"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_b282d9cf-0120-42bc-9036-3bd48f925d1e","target":"nwtN_0f5340ab-a217-423f-b5f7-0a149f3217e8","id":"nwtE_d0a8fa82-36ac-4c28-837b-aa38b8f2cdb6"},"position":{"x":null,"y":null},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_0f5340ab-a217-423f-b5f7-0a149f3217e8","target":"nwtN_91e530f8-4a18-423b-ae2b-0f87ae72d824","id":"nwtE_a4051f32-f6fe-451e-b153-e4de31f4808b"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""},{"data":{"source":"nwtN_0f5340ab-a217-423f-b5f7-0a149f3217e8","target":"nwtN_e79b5f83-1e09-485f-83cb-f85c9c6dae25","id":"nwtE_70a31acd-428d-47be-a981-38107a83d2e1"},"position":{},"group":"edges","removed":false,"selected":false,"selectable":true,"locked":false,"grabbable":true,"classes":""}]
});

                var api = cy.expandCollapse({
                    layoutBy: {
                        name: "cose-bilkent",
                        animate: "end",
                        randomize: false,
                        fit: true
                    },
                    fisheye: true,
                    animate: true,
                    undoable: false,
                    expandCueImage :"icon-plus.png",
                    collapseCueImage:"icon-minus.png"
                });


                document.getElementById("collapseRecursively").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    api.collapseRecursively(cy.$(":selected"));
                });

                document.getElementById("expandRecursively").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    api.expandRecursively(cy.$(":selected"));
                });

                document.getElementById("collapseAll").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    api.collapseAll();
                });

                document.getElementById("expandAll").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    api.expandAll();
                });

            });
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 75vh;
  width: 100vw;
  float: left;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
  <title>cytoscape-expand-collapse.js demo</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/layout-base/layout-base.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cose-base/cose-base.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-cose-bilkent/cytoscape-cose-bilkent.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-expand-collapse@4.0.0/cytoscape-expand-collapse.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>cytoscape-expand-collapse demo</h1>

  <b id="collapseAll" style="cursor: pointer;color: darkred">Collapse all</b> / <b id="expandAll" style="cursor: pointer; color: darkslateblue">Expand all</b> <br/>
  <b id="collapseRecursively" style="cursor: pointer; color: darksalmon">Collapse selected recursively</b> / <b id="expandRecursively" style="cursor: pointer; color: darkmagenta">Expand selected recursively</b>

  <div id="cy"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm actually using that and trying to make an edit for their extension. The issue with their extension I'm trying to fix is that when nodes are collapsed they are actually removed from the workspace, and cannot be interacted with. 

If you are doing anything externally, and want to select or delete a node that is collapsed it doesn't exist, and if you wanted to delete it, then expand the node it is under, it re-adds the node.

I'm trying to edit it so instead of removing the nodes it applies a class to it which sets those nodes to display: none, so they are hidden, but still interactable.

Comment: Please edit your question. Add your current code and a fitting description of your issue.

Comment: Updated, hopefully it's more understandable.